# Where do we "import" the stuff from?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I am assuming that all of us are familiar with `import java.util*;` :)

I just wanted to know, do we physically store these classes on our computer, and if so, where? Or do we need some sort of internet connection.

I am assuming it has something to do with JAVA VM. But I honestly don't know for sure.

Why can't we just `import java.*`;

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + O` is not Java. It is eclipse.

Comment: @AndyTurner I added the eclipse tag,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class files are physically stored on your computer. For example, go look in %JRE directory%/lib/rt.jar. Look in the archive file and you will see java packages (you can find java.util.ArrayList.class for example).

You can certainly import java.* but you will still need to qualify the paths for every package that comes after java.*

Answer (score 2):

User-defined classes are normally imported from locations specified in the [class path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)).

I say "normally" because it depends upon where your class loader loads them from - and given that you can write a custom class loader, it isn't necessary from the class path.